# ¿Cómo solucionar este error al compilar en Apache Cordova?

Tags: apache, cordova

He actualizado algunas cosas en el `SDK Manager` y `Android` para Cordova, pero al tratar de hacer build me sale el siguiente error, ¿Alguna solución?

[image: Error en Cordova]

Comment: Bienvenido Yeltsin. Intenta darle algún contexto a tu pregunta añadiendo las versiones de Apache Cordova y del sistema windows que estás usando. Si puedes, también añade alguna explicación que facilite comprender el problema, como que el error parece producirse por usar rutas demasiado largas.

Answer (score 1):

Si realizaste una actualización y por tu mensaje de error, dentro de tu archivo: `gradle.properties` (si no existe puedes agregarlo al root de tu proyecto) agrega:

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

He solucionado el problema moviendo mi proyecto a una dirección mas corta y también editando project.properties creo que tenia algunas lib repetidas.

Mi dirección era así **E:\adt-bundle\Workspace\myproyecto** y lo eh movido a **E:\myproyecto**.

En **project.propertis** tenia los siguiente códigos y he eliminado las dos ultimas lineas.

```
target=android-23
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=cordova-google-play-services/myproyecto-google-play-services_lib
cordova.gradle.include.1=phonegap-plugin-push/myproyecto-push.gradle
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v13:23+
# cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+
# android.library.reference.2=cordova-google-play-services/myproyecto-google-play-services_lib
```

Comment: Hola Yeltsin, seria bueno que mejores un poco esta respuesta, agregando los cambios que hiciste en project.properties y explicando bien que significa una "direccion mas corta". Sino es posible que tu respuesta acabe eliminada pues asi como esta no es util para otros usuarios. Saludos!